# php upload xml to google api

Tags: php, xml, upload, curl, google-api

I need some help with this problem, please.
For days I have been trying now.

The retrieving off feeds and parsing them is not really a problem, but
Uploading data in the form off xml is?

The code below is partially from the google docs samplecode also, but obviously it's not working.

I hope someone else is more into the google api workings, because I have no idea.
Currently, I am only attempting to add a tag to a photo in an album.
Once that works, I can probably do the rest also.

```
public function postTag() { 
    $query='smarty'; 
    $this->updateOptie('tag', $query); 
    $feedUrl = $this->creeerFeedUrl('myalbum', false); 
    $picasa = $this->parseFeed( $feedUrl ); 
    $gphoto = $picasa['gphoto'][0];    
    $gphotoid = $gphoto['id']; 

    //return $gphotoid; 
    ////////////////////sofar no problem//////////////////  



     $tag = "mytag"; 
       $data = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <title>$tag</title>
    <category scheme=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind\" term=\"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#tag\"/> 
</entry>";    
    $albumid = 'myalbum'; 
    $itemsFeedURL = $this->krijgPicasaBasisUrl(). "/albumid/$albumid/photoid/$gphotoid"; 
    $len=strlen($data); 

    $headers = array( 
        "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->auth, 
        "GData-Version: 2", 
        'Content-Type: application/atom+xml', 
        "Content-Length: $len", 
        ); 

      $ch = curl_init();    /* Create a CURL handle. */ 


      /* Set cURL options. */ 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $itemsFeedURL); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); 
     $result = curl_exec($ch);  /* Execute the HTTP request. */
       $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      curl_close($ch);           /* Close the cURL handle. */
     return $info;
```

thanks, rich

Comment: Your quoting goes wrong where you assign `$data` - is that just on SO, or in your source too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your quoting is broken. The code as you posted in your quesion can't work, because $data contains unescaped double quotes `"`. You need to escape them all like so: `\"`. If this is that way in the code, that may already be the problem.
2. Use `echo curl_error()` after the curl_exec() call to see whether something went wrong during the upload.

Comment: Well, curl can act differently on your own server depending on settings. And the quoting was probably not that way on the picasa site, was it? Can you post a link?

Comment: Thanks, my fault. This was just on SO. I copypasted it again right out off the picasa light class?

Comment: I don't know much about curl settings on the server and the way that it can affect certain requests? I wil look up the link for picasalight. It's the only one out there I could find, that is not related to zend.

Comment: Just add `echo curl_error(); ` right in between the curl_exec() and the curl_info() lines. What happens? Do any error messages come up? What happens anyway, do you get any error messages?

Comment: Well, what's the value of `$itemsFeedURL`? Put in a `echo $itemsFeedURL;`

Comment: Try opening the URL you specified in your browser. It returns `Invalid entity id: tsa_ch`. That's probably your problem - sounds like an invalid albbum or something. Also, when I open the base URL http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/rich3607/, I don't see any albums there. I think you can sort this out now, I'm off for tonight. `Night!

Comment: thanks for your help, I think thats probably due to the fact that I set the album to private? maybe that is something I should investigate?

Comment: I finally found the problem
It was in the itemsfeedUrl--there is a difference in using--/albumid/$albumid--and----/album/$albumid--because with the latter you can identify the album with it's name.